# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference in onDataChange

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
@Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot mDataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String suhu = mDataSnapshot.child("Suhu").getValue().toString();
                    Suhuu.setText(suhu);
                    final Float nilai = Float.valueOf(suhu);
                     if (nilai >= 22 && nilai <= 33) {
                        kondisi.setText("Ideal");
                    } else if (nilai >= 34 && nilai <= 59) {
                        kondisi.setText("Panas");
                    } else if (nilai < 22) {
                        kondisi.setText("Dingin");
                    } else if (nilai > 60) {
                        kondisi.setText("Sangat Panas");
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

i have a problem when i run my code, i want to fetch data from firebase and show graphic to android studio. How to handle it?
`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXDGk.jpg)

Comment: for (DataSnapshot mDataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String suhu = mDataSnapshot.child("Suhu").getValue().toString();

this is my code 84

Comment: can you atleast post your onDataChange code?

Comment: `getValue()` returns null...

Comment: @LecheDeCrema the code can be seen in my post, please help me

Comment: @TylerV what do I have to do?

Comment: Figure out why it returns null and either guard against that if null is possible or fix it so it doesn't return null.

Answer (score 0):

The diagnostic is telling you that you are attempting to invoke `toString()` on the value `null`.  If the code presented is to blame, then that can only be arising from `mDataSnapshot.child("Suhu").getValue()` returning `null`.  You need to accommodate that possibility one way or another.

One alternative would be to use `String.valueOf(Object)` instead of `Object.toString()`.  That is:

```
String suhu = String.valueOf(mDataSnapshot.child("Suhu").getValue());
```

That will produce `"null"` when `getValue()` returns `null`, and otherwise will produce the result of invoking `toString()` on the value.

I am inclined to guess, however, that you *also* want to look into why `getValue()` is returning `null`.  You don't seem to have expected that possibility, and it might be a sign that something is going wrong elsewhere in your program.  At minimum, you should come to an understanding of why that happens in order to be confident that it is correct.